# Android TCP server and NVT

Tags: java, android, android-studio, tcp, tcpserver

I created an Android app, which acts as a TCP server (with `TcpServer`).
It works fine with any byte except with the byte 0xFF.
Indeed, I use Docklight as TCP client, and sometimes, for an unknown reason, it skips half the 0xFF.

Example: I send 0x10 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xAB, and I receive 0x10 0xFF 0xFF 0xAB

I know that NVT skips the 0xFF, but what is strange, is that Docklight doesn't allow to enable/disable NVT, but sometimes everything is received well, and sometimes half the 0xFF are skipped.

It seems that on Android `TcpServer` side, there is no option to set (or not) NVT.

Do you have some ideas why it sometimes works, and why sometimes the 0xFF are skipped?